# Error parsing reference: is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format

Tags: docker, jenkins, nexus, sonatype

Im trying to make a jenkins pipline that clones code from git and build a docker image then push it to nexus registry
so thats what in my jenkins file :

```
pipeline{
    agent any

    environment{
        DOCKERHUB_CREDENTIALS=credentials('docker_hub')
        NEXUS_CREDENTIALS = credentials('nexus')
        
    }

    stages{
        
        stage('Build'){

            steps{
                sh 'docker build -t my-app .'
            }

        }

        stage('Login'){
            steps{
                sh 'echo $NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_PSW | docker login -u $NEXUS_CREDENTIALS_USR --password-stdin http://localhost:8095/repository/docker-private-repo/'
            }

        }
        stage('Push'){

            steps{
                sh 'docker tag my-app:latest http://localhost:8095/docker-private-repo/my-app:latest'
                sh 'docker push http://localhost:8095/docker-private-repo/my-app:latest'
            }

        }
    }
    post{
        always{
            sh 'docker logout'
        }
    }
}
```

for cloning the git code im using pipeline SCM , anyway the build stage and login stage are working fine but for the pushing stage i get this error "Error parsing reference: "http://localhost:8095/docker-private-repo/my-app:latest" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format" i dont know what wrong with the tag command ? how can i solve this ?

Comment: Image and registry names don't have the `https://` scheme prefixed.

Comment: so i should remove the ```http://``` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I Had to remove `https://` from the url now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This might be a more niche answer but in our case the problem was related to this change, which is a breaking change (but the only thing is that you need to update the variables to their current equivalents): *Remove deprecated predefined CI_BUILD_* variables* in GitLab.

In our exact case, in the previous version **8.x** we had `CI_BUILD_TAG`, while in our current version **9.0+** we have `CI_COMMIT_TAG`.

More details here:
[Backend: Remove deprecated predefined CI_BUILD_* variables](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/352957)